# Decrypt text created with Rijndael method in powershell from a php script

Tags: php, powershell, encryption

Can someone please help me with a php script to decrypt a value in php that is being created in powershell using the Rijndael key.

The powershell script I've used to create it is below

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll') | out-null 
$XCADMPass = "CloudyTest"
$r = new-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged  # use Rijndael  symmetric key encryption
$c = $r.CreateEncryptor((1..16), (1..16))    # Set the key and initialisation vector to 128-bytes each of (1..16)
$ms = new-Object IO.MemoryStream
$cs = new-Object Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream $ms,$c,"Write" # Target data stream, transformation, and mode
$sw = new-Object IO.StreamWriter $cs
$sw.Write($XCADMPass)       # Write the string through the crypto stream into the memory stream
$sw.Close()
$cs.Close()
$ms.Close()
$r.Clear()
[byte[]]$result = $ms.ToArray()      # Byte array from the encrypted memory stream
$encPass = [Convert]::ToBase64String($result)
```

The encrypted value is   `yD3/YeGk64JJ2LUI20mo8Q==`

I've tried using mcrypt_decrypt but can't figure out the correct way to get my original text.

This is what i've tried

```
$input = "yD3/YeGk64JJ2LUI20mo8Q==";
$key = "12345678910111213141516";
$data = base64_decode($input);
$iv = substr($data, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

$decrypted = rtrim(
mcrypt_decrypt(
    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
    $key,
    substr($data, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)),
    MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
    $iv
),
"\0"
);
```

I'm clearly going wrong somewhere so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wrong key on the PHP side. The proper key would be `"#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#10#11#12#13#14#15#16"`.

Comment: I changed the key to what the recommendation but now the key is to long and mcrypt_decrypt() throws a warning

Comment: @Vesper `#`? Sure it shouldn't be `\x01..\x16`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `#` seems to be of wrong language. Sorry.

Comment: So i changed the key to `\x01..\x16` and that sorts out the warning but doesn't decrypt to the right string.

Comment: @Shadoweski My PHP is a little rusty, not sure `..` works inside a string. Try `"\x01\x02\x03\x04.."` and so on

Comment: Sorry I acutally tried `$key = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16";`

Comment: Try using the same for `$iv` as I don't see that the encrypted value contains 16 bytes of IV.

Comment: I've just tried changing the `$iv` to the same as $key. Still no luck. Just decrypts it to a different but incorrect value

Comment: The values are hex, so try: "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10"

Comment: @Iridium That is spot on, works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that help with this. I'll show the final code for anyone else that runs into similar issues.

Powershell

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll') | out-null 
$XCADMPass = "CloudyTest"
$r = new-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged  # use Rijndael  symmetric key encryption
$c = $r.CreateEncryptor((1..16), (1..16))    # Set the key and initialisation vector to 128-bytes each of (1..16)
$ms = new-Object IO.MemoryStream
$cs = new-Object Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream $ms,$c,"Write" # Target data stream, transformation, and mode
$sw = new-Object IO.StreamWriter $cs
$sw.Write($XCADMPass)       # Write the string through the crypto stream into the memory stream
$sw.Close()
$cs.Close()
$ms.Close()
$r.Clear()
[byte[]]$result = $ms.ToArray()      # Byte array from the encrypted memory stream
$encPass = [Convert]::ToBase64String($result)
```

PHP

```
$input = "yD3/YeGk64JJ2LUI20mo8Q==";
$iv = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10";
$key = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10";    
$data = base64_decode($input);


$decrypted = rtrim(
mcrypt_decrypt(
MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
$key,
$data,
MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
$iv
),
"\0"
);

echo $decrypted;
```